# How to read in datasets from multiple directories and merge all datasets in each directory in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to read in multiple data files from different directories, and I want to merge all files in each directory and list them into the environment. The data I am working on is NHANES.

For example, if only do this to NHANES 1999-2000.

```
  nhanes_names <- dir(here("data","raw", "NHANES","1999-2000"))
  nhanes_directory <- here("data","raw", "NHANES", "1999-2000", nhanes_names)
  
  nhanes_1999to2000<-nhanes_directory %>%
    set_names(nhanes_names) %>%
    map(read_rds) %>%
    reduce(full_join, by = "seqn")
```

I am wondering if there is a tidy way to apply the code to all folders (1999-2000, 2001-2002,..., 2013-2014) using `purrr`.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445621/r-how-to-read-from-multiple-directories-and-apply-function-on-same-file-names-c?

Comment: Thx, I did read the content from it. But I am still looking for a tidier way to do it. Currently, I use for loop to solve the problem, but maybe there are better ways. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something in line with:

```
library(purrr)
library(here)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

list.files(here("data","raw", "NHANES"), 
           recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>% ## get all files
   grep("\\.rds$", ., value = TRUE) %>%             ## reduce to rds files
   map(read_rds) %>%                                ## read in each
   reduce(full_join, by = "seqn")                   ## and merge them
```

---

Return merged files per directory in a list:

```
library(purrr)
library(here)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

list.dirs(here("data","raw", "NHANES"), recursive = FALSE) %>% ## get all subdirs 
  map(function(sdir) {                                         ## map over all subdirs
      fns <- list.files(sdir, "\\.rds$", full.names = TRUE)    ## get all files in sdir
      map(fns, read_rds) %>%                                   ## read each
          reduce(full_join, by = "seqn")                       ## and merge them
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The code works but it would generate a lot of variables with the same name but with suffix such as variable.x, variable.y.  I would like to merge datasets in each directory first (that is, if I have 9 different directories, I would have 9 different combined datasets), and then I could list them to the environment and merge them later.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! That works perfectly well!